# Create Instance for different class with different constructors

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-core

I have two classes with different constructors.
There is one parameter

```
 public TagService(IRepositoryAsync<Tag> tagRespository):base(tagRespository)
 {
      _tagRespository = tagRespository;
 }
```

There are two parameters.

```
 public AdsService(IRepositoryAsync<Ads> iadsRepository,IUnitOfWork unitOfWork):base(iadsRepository)
 {
      this._iadsRepository = iadsRepository;
      this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
 }
```

At the beginning, I used below to initialize the class.

```
//services have different constractors
Service = (TEntityService)System.Activator.CreateInstance(
   typeof(TEntityService),
   new object[] { _repository, _unitOfWork }
);
```

But, it will not work for only one parameter. Is there any better way for above scenario. I want to create a method which allows creating a different class with the different parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds that you need a Dependency Injection (DI) library, like [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), [Niject](http://www.ninject.org/), [Simple injector](https://simpleinjector.org) etc

E.g. Simple Injector:

```
// 1. Create a new Simple Injector container
container = new Container();

// 2. Configure the container (register)
container.Register<IRepositoryAsync<Tag>, TagService>();
container.Register<IRepositoryAsync<Ads>, AdsService>();
container.Register<IUnitOfWork >();

// 3. Verify your configuration
container.Verify();

//4  
var service = container.GetInstance<TEntityService>();
```

Comment: Is Autofac supported in XUnit Core? Could you share me a simple guideline link? Thanks

Comment: It supports .net core, so xunit works also. This is a good link to start with: http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a method which is enable to create different class with different parameter in constructor.

Well I guess the easiest way to do this is to check each case.

```
public static TEntityService CreateService(object[] constructorParameters) {
    if (constructorParameters.Length == 1 &&
        constructorParameters[0] is IRepositoryAsync<Tag>) {
        return (TEntityService)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TagService), constructorParameters);
    } else if (constructorParameters.Length == 2 &&
        constructorParameters[0] is IRepositoryAsync<Ads> &&
        constructorParameters[1] is IUnitOfWork) {
        return (TEntityService)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AdsService), constructorParameters);
    } else {
        return null; // or you can throw an exception
    }
}
```